# Cause DIV to fill page?

Tags: css, html

I have seen some questions like this, but they are old and none of the solutions have worked for me...

I have a simple html

```
<div id='outer'>
    <div id='nav'></div>
    <div id='content'>
    <!-- html -->
    </div>
    <div id='footer'></div>
</div>
```

and my css

```
#outer {width: 800px; margin: 30px auto;}
#nav {height: 40px; width: 800px;}
#content {width: 800px;}
#footer {height: 40px; width: 800px;}
```

Content seems to choose its own height and stays that height no matter what is in it.
How can I cause it (`#content`) to fill the space of its content?

Comment: You mean before adding content you need to keep the space reserved in #content?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more descriptive. There is plenty of content in `#content`, but it is always a smaller size... so, `#footer` always cuts into the content.

Comment: u can set min-height u want.........

Comment: i've answered this question 2 times in the past 2 days. i'll add answer below again in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of the `#content` should automatically increase until you are applying `float` or `position` properties to the child elements. Try giving `overflow: auto` to `#content` (if you are using `float`) may be this solves the problem.

or use alternate of `float` property like `display:inline` or `display: inline-block`.

If you are not giving `float` to the child elements of `#content` then try using `clear: both`.

I hope this tips will help you.

Answer (score 1):

`#content` is set to `height:auto` by default which sets the height based on the content. If you're asking for a footer that will stay at the bottom of the screen even when there is not enough content to fill the screen then you need to use some sort of 'sticky footer'.

[Ryan Fait's sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) is the best one I've used.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gWdQj/

The height of navbar + content + footer will always be a minimum of 100% of viewport. If it's more, this css will auto adjust the height accordingly.

HTML

```
<div id='outer'>
    <div id='nav'></div>
    <div id='content'>
    <!-- html -->
    </div>
    <div id='footer'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, #outer
{
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}

#nav
{
    height:38px; /* this is an exmple height. Insert your own. */
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#footer
{
    height:48px; /* this is an example height. Insert your own. */
    border:1px solid purple;
}

#content
{
    min-height: calc(100% - 38px - 48px); /* css3 function to calculate content height, which is 100% of parent minus navbar height - footer height */
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 38px - 48px);
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 38px - 48px);
}
```

Comment: The problem with calc is that it calculates based on visible space... so if your window is smaller than the content of the page, the footer will sit inside content.

Comment: as you said, it calculates based on visible space. So if your window is smaller than the content of the page, the footer will not sit inside content.